nginx `try_files` do not return the right file
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    # Map to determine the preferred image format
    map $http_accept $image_suffix {
        default "";
        "~*image/avif" ".avif";
        "~*image/webp" ".webp";
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location /public/images/ {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;

            # Extract the base name without extension
            set $base_uri $uri;
            if ($uri ~* ^(.+)\.(jpeg|jpg|png)$) {
                set $base_uri $1;
            }

            add_header X-debug-image $base_uri$image_suffix;
            add_header X-debug $uri;
            add_header Vary Accept;

            # Try serving the preferred format or fallback to the original
            try_files $base_uri$image_suffix $uri =404;

        }
    }
}

# pwd
/usr/share/nginx/html
# ls -l public/images
bkw2p3rvoe.avif
bkw2p3rvoe.jpeg
bkw2p3rvoe.webp

When I request my image http://localhost:8181/public/images/bkw2p3rvoe.jpeg in the browser, it returns the jpeg, but it should return the .avif:
Request headers:
accept:
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7```

Response headers:
content-type: image/jpeg
vary: Accept
x-debug: /public/images/bkw2p3rvoe.jpeg
x-debug-image: /public/images/bkw2p3rvoe.avif


You cannot use if in a location like that. There used to be a page explaining this, but it's disappeared.
You could use a regular expression location instead.
For example:
location /public/images/ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location ~* ^(?<base_uri>.+)\.(jpeg|jpg|png)$ {

        add_header X-debug-image $base_uri$image_suffix;
        add_header X-debug $uri;
        add_header Vary Accept;

        try_files $base_uri$image_suffix $uri =404;
    }
}

Use a named capture, as  numeric captures are reset whenever Nginx evaluates another regular expression. Because your map contains a regular expression and is evaluated after the location (where $image_suffix is first used), $1 will be empty.
All three add_header statements must appear within the same block, and need to be inside the regular expression location to have access to the capture.

okay, there is just one issue with your answer: I added add_header X-debug-image $1$image_suffix; and it returns x-debug-image: .webp

Sorry, didn't notice the $base_uri variable in the add_header statement. Answer updated.

maybe you made a typo bcz its still the same code, $1$image_suffix prints .webp

It's an obscure problem with numeric captures. Answer updated.

there is a typo: (?<base_uri>).+) should be (?<base_uri>.+), can you edit? i'll accept your answer as it is working besides that. thanks
